# Opening a MySQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, fedora

I have read that when I open a connection on a MySQL database the instruction `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` it was not necessary with the new drivers in fact the connection was opened without errors, after two years I took up the same project from my github.com repository and with the same software installed (MySQL, Apache Tomcat, etc.) the connection did not work without the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` instruction, On what it depends on? Why does it work once and another it does not work?

Comment: The `Class.forName("...")` is not necessary anymore with newer Java versions / newer JDBC drivers. If you are using an older Java version and/or JDBC driver, it is still necessary.

Comment: Could it be because I switched from Wildfly 10.1 to Tomcat 8.0.50?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mysql connector J 8.0? The [class name per the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-driver-name.html) is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.